# Play Music stored on ubuntu via Android device

Tags: android, music, media

I have a music collection of mp3 files stored on my ubuntu machine which I use primarily as a media laptop.  I have a 1tb hard drive so for all practical purposes I have tons of disk space for this machine.

My android device *(Galaxy S5)* has very limited storage in comparison; however, it is ideal to play music through, though it is not ideal to store the music on my android device.

Is there a method in which I can use my ubuntu machine essentially as a music server, allowing my android phone to see and play all of the files stored on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Emby-Server is great for that .. i can listen to my music, view photos, even watch tv because my server has a tuner connected .. the emby app is available in the google play store

If you take a lot of photos and would like to save some space .. Syncthing is also a nice program that will sync any files on the phone you want when you are connected to your local network over wifi and you can make it a one way sync so once transferred you can delete them from your phone and they will be saved on your server... and viewed with emby-server ..

Then Emby app will let you access your files from any wifi .. and cell too i guess but that could get expensive .... so you always have access to your files.